# mysql query . need assistance

Tags: mysql, database

say if the table trap has column 'id' and rows contents as

```
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
```

---

```
SELECT id FROM trap
WHERE id<10 and id>12
```

this doesn't give any output

but if

```
SELECT id FROM trap
WHERE id>7 and id<14
```

give me the required output i.e.,

```
8
9
10
11
12
13
```

Comment: no integer is bigger than 12 AND smaller than 10.

Comment: AND should be OR in the first query, as I am guessing the range you are looking for is less than 10 OR greater than 12

Comment: It would help for you to identify what you are trying to do. If you want to identify what rows have a value between two numbers, then your second form is correct, as you discovered. If you want to get any numbers that are less than one number and also you want to get any numbers that are more than another number, you have to combine those two things with an OR not an AND. But which is right depends on your objective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're using the AND operator where you should be using OR.

```
SELECT id FROM trap WHERE id<10 OR id>12
```

Obviously `id` cannot be both 10 AND 12 at the same time, one box can only hold one value.

Alternatively you can write the statement as:

```
SELECT id FROM trap WHERE NOT(id BETWEEN 10 AND 12)
```

The reason that `SELECT id FROM trap WHERE id>7 and id<14` **does** work is that it **is** possible for a value to be `BETWEEN` 8 AND 13 (inclusive) at the same time.
However no way can a value ever the smaller than 10 and larger than 12 at the same time.

So if the conditions are mutually exclusive you must use `OR`, if the conditions do not exclude one and other then you must use `AND`.
You can wrap a test inside a `NOT()` to reverse the test, this is because `AND` and `OR` are exact opposites.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're mistaken, or you've phrased the question wrong.

It's impossible for id < 10 and id > 12 to be true at the same time. That's why you aren't getting any results for your first query.

What you're looking for is:

```
SELECT id FROM trap WHERE id<10 OR id>12
```